# Tauri: how to change dynamically the tray icon

Tags: tauri

Tauri app.
The app has just tray and I'm listening to some changes in the background. In case a change happened I want to change the tray icon. Did someone face this issue and has any idea how to resolve this?

I tried to delete and start a new tray but did not got much success there